# Storing strings in arrays and splitting strings

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a Java issue on a uni assignment. We've been given a file that has a set of information listed as such (there's more, this is just a formatting example):

57363 Joy Ryder D D C P H H C D 
72992 Laura Norder H H H D D H H H 
71258 Eileen Over C F C D C C C P

For the life of me, I can't work out how to store this in an array, AND I need it split because the letters need to be converted to a number and averaged, which will then need to be stored into a second array.

I'm new-ish to Java, so a lot of the types of things that require an import at the start of the code are unknown to me, so explaining the code changes in any replies would be greatly appreciated. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentGPA_16997761 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    //get file
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of the file containing student information: ");
    String gradeFile = kb.next();
    Scanner grades = new Scanner(new File(gradeFile));

    if (new File(gradeFile).exists()) {
      while (grades.hasNextLine()) {
        System.out.println(grades.nextLine());
      }
    }

    //student identification number, a first name, a surname, then 8 individual alphabetic characters that represent the
    //unit grades for the student. Hence, each line of data in the text file represents a student and the grades
    //they achieved in 8 units of study

    //need to make array to hold student information
    //need to make array that holds student id and GPA

  }
}
```

I know that it works, as the System.out.println prints out the lines as I expected them to be read, but I can't figure out how to store them. I think I miiight be able to get the split working, but that'll still need the array/arraylist first...

Comment: Spit will not need any ArrayList/Array. Split can directly called on String to get array then that array can be used to sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split a string into an array using a delimiter.  In your example, if all first and last names do not contain spaces themselves, you can do the following:

```
while (grades.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = grades.nextLine();
    String[] parts = line.split(" ");

    // get the basics
    String id = parts[0];
    String firstname = parts[1];
    String lastname = parts[2];

    // extract the grades
    int size = parts.length - 3;
    String[] gradelist = new String[size];
    System.arraycopy(parts, 3, gradelist, 0, size);

    // do something with the grades
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is especially good at OOP - Object Oriented Programming. Each line of your input file is a student, which is a perfect example of an object you can define. Let's define a Student class that holds the desired information:

```
public class Student{
    public final int ID;
    public final String name;
    private LinkedList<Character> grades;
    private double grade;    

    public Student(int i; String n, String[] g){
        ID = i;
        name = n;
        grades = new LinkedList<Character>();
        for(String s : g){
            grades.add(s.charAt(0));
        }

        //Do parsing to turn a list of letters into a grade here...
    }

    public double getGrade(){
        return grade;
    }
}
```

Then you can construct students to store the information as you read it. Put this where your current while loop is in your given code.

```
LinkedList<Student> students = new LinkedList<Student>();
while (grades.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] line = grades.nextLine().split("\\s");
    Student s = new Student(Integer.parseInt(line[0]), 
        line[1] + " " + line[2], 
        Arrays.copyOfRange(line, 3, line.length));
   students.add(s); 
}
```

Then do work on students as necessary.

Comment: I was looking back over this today and I'm wondering, where it adds the new Student...I'm not sure how to phrase this, so hopefully this makes sense. Because it's a while loop, is the code going to have issues or anything with how each new Student is "Student s"? I was trying to code something today and I was worried it would just overwrite the old data with new data since they were all "Student s". Or since it's a new Student, would it not mind the same name?